# (Java, JSON) Get data from a playlist with a deleted item using Youtube API

Tags: java, android, json, youtube, youtube-api

I searched for a lot of topics here on SO and I came pretty far. But now I have a problem, concerning how to correctly read data from this URL: 
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLsksxTH4pR3KtrWWeupRy5h0Di7N_MufB?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50

In position 22 there is a video that is rejected from Youtube and therefore blocked, so one cannot watch it. I now have the problem that I cannot successfully skip that entry and continue with the next one. Even though there are 50 entries in the above URL, my application will only display 21, stopping where that blocked video would be.

I tried to use the JsonObject "status" of that video and checking if it has the value "rejected", but I couldn't do it.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance :)

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> msg = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Bitmap> thumb = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

public void getData()
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLsksxTH4pR3KtrWWeupRy5h0Di7N_MufB?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50");

    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        String _response= EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(_response);

        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("video");

            String title1 = jsonObject.getString("title");
            title.add(title1);

            String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
            URL url1 = new URL(thumbUrl);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url1.openConnection().getInputStream());
            thumb.add(bmp);
            String url;
            try {

                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
                msg.add(url);
            } catch (JSONException ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use the JsonObject "status" of that video and checking if
>   it has the value "rejected", but I couldn't do it.

To get all items from `items` JSONArray without blocked items. use [JSONObject.has](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) method for checking is `status` object is available or not before accessing other keys from `video` JSONObject.like:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("video");
if(jsonObject.has("status")){
  // ignore video object

}else{
  //... get other thumbnail, player objects
}
```

Comment: I could swear to God that I tried exactly the same... Man, do I feel stupid now... Anyways, thanks a lot! That worked perfectly! :)